# Decoding data into HTML

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a URL that returns JSON data and is constantly being updated. I'm trying to get the contents of this data to show up on my site. Here is JSON file ([url](http://www.dadsbeingawesome.com/data.json))

I only need the contents from the 'images' (pretty far down there) array ... when I try and use just simple php code:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($str, true);

$result = array();
foreach($json['designs']['images'] as $image); {
     $result[] = $image['url'];
}

echo $result;
```

I just keep returning 'Array' on the browser. If I replace `echo` with `print_r` I get this: Array ( [0] => SWZ51F ) which is correct, but i would like it to display in HTML format.

Comment: use `echo $result[0];`

Comment: What do you mean by html format?

Comment: @AlivetoDie ... that worked(ish) it's only pulling up 1 result ... i have over 1000 ... how do i bring up all of them?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer ... the data is going to be displayed on a webpage with the url field pulling up an actual image ... with the rest of the data being referenced through different 'tags' so users can filter through easier

Comment: What do you mean HTML format?  `$result` is an array, you have to access the elements to see it. @Doug linking a php tutorial from scratch does nothing, and it is insulting to someone learning. Why would that be a 'good place to start' exactly?

Comment: thanks @Doug ... i know php, i just don't know much about json

Comment: @brianforan ... thanks! i need to display all of the different results on a webpage ... was able to do that with the first comment ... but it's only bringing up one result out of thousands

Comment: Json put simply is an array, usually a multidimensional array.

Comment: @broserdooder `foreach($result as $key=>$value) { echo $key . ' => ' . $value ."\n"; }`

Comment: Your `$result` variable holds an array, and you can't echo array the way you echo strings. You need to loop through the array, and echo each consecutive value.

Comment: `\n` probably won't work if this is going onto a website. Maybe do `<br>` instead, or wrap it all in `echo nl2br()`

Comment: @brianforan do i put the suggested `foreach()` inside the current `foreach()` loop?

Comment: @broserdooder it really doesnt matter, but if you did you would change that $image to $key=>$value or whatever sort of association you wanted instead of key/value, like how lorenz had it. The answer that said the JSON is invalid is incorrect, I don't know why he/she thought that.

Comment: @broserdooder you want to all images url the $result or a single image url in the $result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the loop, `$result` is an array of all image URLs. You can loop through it to output the html. A basic approach would be :

```
foreach ($result as $url) {
    echo '<img src="' . $url . '"/><br/>';
}
```

Or use a single loop:

```
foreach($json['designs']['images'] as $image); { 
    echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '"/><br/>';
}
```

Comment: we don't need loop for a single image just use this: `echo '<img alt="" src="'.$json['designs']['images'][0]['url'].'">';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This is for ALL IMAGES URL:

```
$result = array();
foreach($json['designs']['images'] as $image){
    $result[] = $image['url'];
}
var_dump($result);
```

This is for single IMAGE URL:

```
$result=$json['designs']['images'][0]['url'];
echo $result;
```